# HttpServlet missing even though servlet-api.jar is in class path

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to compile a simple servlet and I am getting an exception that HttpServlet, among other classes, is missing. Please note that I am including servlet-api.jar. What am I missing here?

```
jdk1.8.0.05/bin/javac -cp "/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/servlet-api.jar" StockLookup.java

StockLookup.java:4: error: package javax.servlet.html does not exist
import javax.servlet.html.*;
^

StockLookup.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
public class StockLookup extends HttpServlet {
                                 ^
  symbol: class HttpServlet

StockLookup.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
                   ^
  symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
  location: class StockLookup

StockLookup.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
                                               ^
  symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
  location: class StockLookup
```

Comment: I think you meant to import `javax.servlet.http.*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are importing a package that does not exist...

Should be

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;
```

Comment: Wow, I am going blind. Thank you for pointing out the issue.